# Pago de Horas Extras Python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa para solicitar al usuario las horas y la tarifa por hora utilizando *input* para calcular su paga.

-> En caso de que se trabaje más de 40 horas, se multiplicará 1.5 veces la tarifa por todas las horas trabajadas por encima de las 40 horas (factor de 1.5 por hora extra).

-> Utilice **45** horas y una tarifa de **10,50** por hora, para probar el programa (el pago debe ser **498,75**). Debe usar *input* para leer *String* y *float* () para convertir la cadena en un número.
h=horas
r=rate o tarifa por hora

> Hice la lógica en Excel antes de escribir el código:

- Si h<=40, se paga normal la hora: normalh = h*r,
- Si h>40, la hora extra se multiplica por 1.5, es decir: (h-40)x(r*1.5)

Al hacerlo así, me da bien en Excel, pero al revisar el código de solución porque no me daba, se estaba multiplicando r*(**0.5**) en lugar de 1.5, alguien sabe porqué se multiplica por 0.5 y no por 1.5? Me pueden ayudar a entender la lógica de esto por favor?

Al multiplicar por 0.5, sí da 498.75, que es el resultado esperado. Copio Código:

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rph = input("Rate per hours:")
r = float(rph)
normalh = h*r

if h>40: 
    normalh = h*r
    extrah = (h-40)*(r*0.5)
    pay = normalh + extrah
    print(pay)
else: 
    pay = h*r
    print(pay)
```

Comment: ```normalh= h×r``` aquí edtas multiplicando todas las horas trabajadas y no las 40 horas por lo que deberías poner ```40*r``` y ahora solo cambia el ```0.5``` por ```1.5```

Comment: Emiliano, el programa te pide que le pagues 1.5 veces la tarifa normal a las personas que trabajan más de 40 horas. Esto significa que se le paga un plus por la cantidad de horas extras trabajadas, en este caso, si trabaja 45 horas, las horas extra son 5. Por lo que se paga un 0.5 más por esas horas extras.

A una persona que trabaja 40 horas, se le paga 1 sueldo, 1 solo sueldo. Mientras que a una persona que trabaja más de 40 horas, se le paga 1 sueldo + 0.5 sueldo de horas extras.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error es al asignarle el valor a `normalh=h*r`
Te falta restas las 40 horas, te deberia quedar así

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rph = input("Rate per hours:")
r = float(rph)

if h>40:    
    normalh=40*r    
    extrah = (h-40)*(r*1.5)  
    pay = normalh + extrah
    print(pay)
else:
    pay = h*r
    print(pay)
```

En **normalh** pongo 40 y que eso siempre se le pagará normal

Comment: Si van a votar en contra podrían decir por lo menos por que razón lo hacen?

Answer (score 0):

```
if h>40: 
normalh = h*r
extrah = (h-40)*(r*0.5)
pay = normalh + extrah
print(pay)
```

en normalh, las horas (h) debiesen ser las 40 de tope, y el factor 1.5, no 0.5

Answer (score -1):

A la variable "normalh" se le debe asignar el valor de "40 * r" cuando la condicion "h>40" es verdadera. En tu caso a "normalh" dentro de la condicion "h>40", le estas asignando el total de horas, por lo que si introduces 45 horas, quiere decir que estas incluyendo las 5 horas extras dentro de 'normalh'.

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rph = input("Rate per hours:")
r = float(rph)
normalh = h*r

if h>40: 
    normalh = 40 * r
    extrah = (h-40)*(r*1.5)
    pay = normalh + extrah
    print(pay)
else: 
    pay = h*r
    print(pay)
```